# How to use the downloaded maven aar file in my Android project?

Tags: android, maven, build.gradle, aar

My Android project download the maven aar file from others' personal maven,it exists in the directory:

```
C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1
```

now I want to use the maven file,how can I configure in my project `build.gradle`,or in my module `build.gradle`.

I have tried many methods to solve the question,including add

```
repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile(name: 'myaarfilename.aar', ext: 'arr')
}
```

in my module`build.gradle`

and add

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavencentral()
        mavenLocal() //to use my local maven aar file
    }
}
```

in my project`build.gradle`

all of these methods does not work, so how can I use the my maven cache aar file ,or how can I configure maven?Hoping somebody can help me ,thanks a lot.

Comment: mavenLocal refers to ~/.m2/ folder

Comment: `compile(name: 'myaarfilename', ext: 'arr')`

Comment: so not only should I add mavenLocal() in repositories ,but also add ~/.m2/folder into it?but I found the file what I want to use does not exist in the directory what you said,can you tell me why

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaxis2aarjar.htm

Comment: it still does not work,I want to know the why Android Studio does not read the maven aar file from my local cache?

Comment: @Liuyanguo The cache is NOT a maven repo.

Comment: Using `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])` just works.

Obviously, you have to drop the `aar` file in the `libs` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Android project download the maven aar file from others' personal maven,it exists in the directory:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1
> ```

Pay attention because the gradle cache folder is NOT a maven repo.

Then:

> ```
> buildscript{
>     repositories{
>         jcenter()
>         mavencentral()
>         mavenLocal() //to use my local maven aar file
>     }
> }
> ```

You are using the `repositories` block inside the `buildscript` and it is NOT related to the `dependencies` like an aar file.

If you have an aar file you can put the file in the `libs` folder and then use:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
 }
repositories{
      flatDir{
              dirs 'libs'
       }
 }
```

Please pay attention because the **aar** file **doesn't contain the transitive dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo **you have to specify the dependencies also in your project**.

Otherwise if you have a maven repo just use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'my_dependencies:X.X.X'
}
```

Comment: Though not solve my problem,but I still agree with your idea,I doubt that if my aar file are wrong.The Android Studio does not read maven file from the directory made me very confused.I depended the okhttp3,once I delete the cache of okhttp3,Android Studio will download okhttp3 from jcenter in the next building,if the cache of okhttp3 exist in the folder,Android Studio won't download from jcenter,but only the package is very strange......

Answer (score -1):

Try adding in the project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {       
        maven { url 'file://' + new File('path/to/repository').canonicalPath }
    }
}
```